# Where are Yianaros's field NPCs?

Tags: black-desert-online

While exploring I found Yanaros's field node. The node manager is the rock, but on radar (see print) there seems to be a second hidden npc called Yanaros Spirit (can see the name on hover).

[image]

The thing is that I cannot find him/it. It appears as a question mark (so it was not met) on radar. How do I find him?

Note: I don't see any mention of the npc in knowledge list (H, under Characters->Kama).

Comment: I haven't been around that area, but usually when that happens other places its for characters who appear at certain times or at different elevations, so try using the 3d map. If you right click the ? on the minimap where does auto-path take you?

Comment: He doesn't seem elevated on map. Autopathing brings me to the exact spot I'm in print screen. There seems to be no tunnel/cave around the area (or if it is I didn't find the entrance). Tried both night and day (in case he appears only at night or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Yianaros Spirit hides from Players**, meaning it is a little difficult to talk to the NPC. If you sneak up to her, you can get close enough to talk to her.

Quick Edit: I also found this during a Google search:

> – Description:
> Yianaros is the Node Manager of Yianaros's Field.
> You may think it looks like an ordinary stone but this stone is actually the spirit Yianaros hiding from you. The beautiful garden is tended to by Yianaros, but she only appears when there is no one else around. Therefore, there is yet a single adventurer who has seen the true form of Yianaros.

From [BDdatabase.net](https://bddatabase.net/us/npc/45566/).

Comment: You can actually sneak and get close enough to talk to it. Would add a print screen but is maintenance right now :).

Comment: I will edit my answer, so you can accept it. I will add the part that you can meet her when sneaking, I've actually never heard that before, interesting. Thank you for this information @zozo :)

Comment: There is a mention about sneaking in the comments here: https://bdocodex.com/us/quest/6003/15/ (you may also need to have the quest but I'm not sure - I had it at the point and didn't test without it)